# How write C++ code to show all possible combinations from two different arrays

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program that chooses from `A {1 2 3}` and `B {4 5 6}` and outputs all possible `C{a b}` where `a` is an integer from `A` and `b` is integer from `B`. I am having trouble connecting the two.

Comment: Why not two nested loop?  Outer loop iterates over elements of A.   Inner loop iterates over elements of B.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    for( auto a1 : a )
    {
        for( auto b1 : b )
        {
            std::cout << a1 << " " << b1 << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this works

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  const int SIZE = 3; //size of arrays
  int A[SIZE] { 1, 2, 3 }; //fill with data
  int B[SIZE] { 4, 5, 6 }; //here too

  for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        std::cout << A[j] << " " << B[i] << std::endl; //print
      }
  }
  system("pause"); //simple pause statement
  return 0; //done
}
```

Just make 2 loops to get all combinations.

Here's the output:

1 4 
1 5 
1 6 
2 4 
2 5 
2 6 
3 4 
3 5 
3 6

also: if you'd like to save that data, you could use a std::vector array.

I hope that helped you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks alot this also worked very well and now I can do for even three different arrays. Thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:  **[*here*](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/)** 
 I think the approach below might fit the question.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n, n1;
   cin>>n;
   cin>>n1;
   int arr_a[n], arr_b[n1];
   for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
       cin >> arr_a[i];
   }
   for (int i = 0 ; i < n1; i++ ) {
       cin >> arr_b[i];
   }
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
       for ( int j = 0; j < n1; j++ ) {
           cout << arr_a[i] << "," << arr_b[j]<<"\n";
       }
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Prashanth. I am marveled at the different ways everyone approached this to get the same solution. Thanks once again.